# NGINX configuration does not acces css and js files in dist folder

Tags: nginx

I have an app in the folder in root.
It shows index.html file, which is in /dist folder but it can't access to css or js folders with styles and app.js.

I tried to modify my server nginx settings, but I can't figure out how to make it as it is ithmany locations connected to different ports.

This is nginx

```
server {

        root /var/www/krzysztofmironczuk/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name krzysztofmironczuk.me www.krzysztofmironczuk.me;

        location /magicbellows {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }

        location /musicfestival {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        }
        
        location /navalnoticeboard {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }

        location /musicapp {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:6000/;
        }

        location /pizzeria {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/; //* this location
                                
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/krzysztofmironczuk.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/krzysztofmironczuk.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.krzysztofmironczuk.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = krzysztofmironczuk.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name krzysztofmironczuk.me www.krzysztofmironczuk.me;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: The "/dist/" folder does not appear in your configuration. Where is it in relation to the value of your `root` directive? What is the exact URL for the files you are attempting to access (check the access log) and what is the exact pathname Nginx should use to locate the file?

Comment: Relation is root/pizzeria/dist but I see in log that it tries to attempt: root/html/
OMG, I'm new to nginx and i didn't want to be an hard user, just wanted to put all my  portfolio projects online in different folders...

Comment: The `root` statement in your configuration points Nginx at the `html` directory. Perhaps you should be using `root /var/www/krzysztofmironczuk/pizzeria/dist;` instead.